# How to get or read the Env variable defined under 'systemPropertyVariables' tag in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

How to get or read the Env variable defined under 'systemPropertyVariables' tag in pom.xml? Have a look at the pom.xml snippet. I want to get the value of 'env' and use it in my code.

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
        <propertyName>${env}</propertyName>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Comment: Hi @Shiv, have you tried anything already ?

Comment: @VdeX I have used it on TestNG class using '@Parameters("env")' annotation.

Comment: tried `System.getProperty("propertyName")`  ?

Comment: Let me try System.getProperty("propertyName")

Comment: @VdeX it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: greate, please accept answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you can get using

```
System.getProperty("propertyName")
```

Thank you